# html5 banners can be lower in size than gif or flashbanners?

Tags: html, flash, canvas, ads

I have some questions and have been trying to get clear answer about without any luck.
The problem I have is that I need to make a banner with a certain image and under 50K in size. This is making me question a lot of techniques and possibilities.

It's a very hard task and I've been trying and googling a lot. Did it in flash and as gif in PS (don’t know if there is a huge difference?). Did all the text in vector and even tried to make the image black and white. Tried to erase everything but the image and set the image properties to very low res but still just reached 79K. I guess I can’t make it smaller…. So I would be very grateful if you could help me. I hope my following questions are not too bad/stupid.

1. If a banner must contain a picture is it going to be a big differ in size when making the banner html5 banner instead of gif or flash file, It still needs to contain the image? As I understand flash is using html5. Is there going to be a huge/any difference?
2. How do you deliver a html5 banner to someone who puts it on there website? In separate files or one, is it depending on who wants it?

If you have any more better options to optimize/minimize the banner please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: What size is your ad? Is it an animated or a static image? Did you try using GIF optimizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is almost always smaller than html5, because a swf file is a binary, compressed format that is decompressed by the Flash player on the client.

Image size between html and Flash delivery isn't a big difference; either way, you need to choose the best compression --  JPG, GIF, or PNG -- for your situation.

Ad networks and sites have varied requirements for html5 banner delivery. You can zip up your files, but you'll have at least two: html and image. Ideally your images are all in one sprite sheet. I recommend reading the IAB guide for HTML banners: http://www.iab.net/html5